# My Documents folder not being redirected via Folder Redirection Group Policy

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, windows-8

I have Folder Redirection applied for `My Documents` to users that log on to Windows 8 machines. The GPO is set and applied using a Windows Server 2003 machine.

The `My Music`, `My Pictures` and `My Videos` folders are all being redirected to the `My Documents` folder in the specified redirection location, and when I click on the library link in the explorer, I see the correct files.

However, when I click the 'Documents' library link, I'm taken to the `My Documents` folder on the local Windows 8 machines.

In the event viewer, I found this entry listed, although clicking the 'More information' link took me to the 404 page on TechNet. -

> Windows failed to apply the Folder Redirection settings. Folder Redirection settings might have its own log file. Please click on the "More information" link.

Can anyone suggest why this may be happening, and how I can fix it? Thanks.

**Edit**

Here is a copy of the full report of the error from the event viewer.

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy
Date:          20/09/2013 12:20:02
Event ID:      1085
Task Category: None
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      
User:          DD\dgard
Computer:      sh070x.dynedrewett.com
Description:
Windows failed to apply the Folder Redirection settings. Folder Redirection settings might have its own log file. Please click on the "More information" link.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy" Guid="{AEA1B4FA-97D1-45F2-A64C-4D69FFFD92C9}" />
    <EventID>1085</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>1</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-09-20T11:20:02.946889800Z" />
    <EventRecordID>192525</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{E8E91B72-8190-4DFA-9A78-5D0CE74EC881}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="928" ThreadID="3644" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>sh070x.dynedrewett.com</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-3207548864-3431316730-922412524-1388" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="SupportInfo1">1</Data>
    <Data Name="SupportInfo2">4404</Data>
    <Data Name="ProcessingMode">1</Data>
    <Data Name="ProcessingTimeInMilliseconds">3993</Data>
    <Data Name="ErrorCode">1003</Data>
    <Data Name="ErrorDescription">Cannot complete this function. </Data>
    <Data Name="DCName">\\shdc3k.dynedrewett.com</Data>
    <Data Name="ExtensionName">Folder Redirection</Data>
    <Data Name="ExtensionId">{25537BA6-77A8-11D2-9B6C-0000F8080861}</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: The event log entry has additional data - could you just copy the entire event (push the "copy" button on the event detail view represented by two paper sheets) and paste it here? It likely contains the information needed to resolve the issue.

Comment: @syneticon-dj - Thanks for the reply. I've updated my question with that information.